# regex for copy pasted mysql table data

Tags: regex

How could I format this so it fits a csv format? I accidentally deleted my table and now I need to export this data.

```
+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| id  | email                           | firstName   | lastName          |
+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
|   6 | email@email.com                 | Person1     | Person1           |
|   7 | email2@email.com                | Person2     | Person2           |
|   8 | email3@email.com                | Person3     | Person3           |
+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

This is a text file I made before, so how could I remove the lines so that it goes like:

```
"6","email@email.com","Person1","Person1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually in Excel (open file, Data -> Text to Columns, Fixed width.

Regex-wise, 2 options:

- replace stuff:

  ```
  s/^\|\s+/"/;
  s/\s+\|\s+/","/g;
  s/\s*\|$/"/;
  ```
- match stuff:

  ```
  s/^\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|$/"$1","$2","$3,"$4"/
  ```

Of course, the exact syntax depends on the language you use.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer in Javascript - RegEx**(No language is mentioned, `picked JS by looking at your profile`)

```
[\w\s.@]+(?=\|)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eT9zC9)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfWCy/2/)

For the given case, only `\w`, `\s`, `.`, `@` are allowed. You can allow more characters as per your convenience

For **Multiline** Text - TextArea

```
var str = $('#regex_string').val()
```

or
For **Single Line** - `Enter` or `\n` removed to make it a single line for storing it in a variable

```
var str = '+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+| id  | email                           | firstName   | lastName          |+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+|   6 | email@email.com                 | Person1     | Person1           ||   7 | email2@email.com                | Person2     | Person2           ||   8 | email3@email.com                | Person3     | Person3           |+-----+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+'

var extractValidString = str.match(/[\w\s.@]+(?=\|)/g).join("").trim().split(/\s+/)
//output ["id", "email", "firstName", "lastName", "6", "email@email.com", "Person1", "Person1", "7", "email2@email.com", "Person2", "Person2", "8", "email3@email.com", "Person3", "Person3"]

//to remove Headers - id, email, firstName, lastName
extractValidString.splice(0,4)

//extract all rows
var arr = [];
while(extractValidString.length>0) {
    //Extract set of 4 elements as you have only 4 columns
    //change second no to allow other columns as per your requirement
    arr.push(extractValidString.splice(0,4))
}

//output
[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
0: Array[4]
    0: "6"
    1: "email@email.com"
    2: "Person1"
    3: "Person1"
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[4]
    0: "7"
    1: "email2@email.com"
    2: "Person2"
    3: "Person2"
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[4]
    0: "8"
    1: "email3@email.com"
    2: "Person3"
    3: "Person3"
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```